# what is the option in doxygen for show xtends?

Tags: java, doxygen

What is the option for doxygen show on Inheritance diagram extens class?

example : public class ThreadIconoAlarma extends Thread

Thankd very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_graphical_hierarchy)=YES along with HAVE_DOT=YES does solves this.